# How to calculate the min/max values from an array of object-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data showing the various data points on the chart.

```
var data = [{name:"s", y:2},{name:"e",y:90},{name:"tt",y:9},{name:"se",y:10}]
```

now i know with simple array you can use the Math.max....and Math.min to calculate the min/max values, not sure how can i achieve the same with an array of objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `Math.max` and `Math.min`. Just `map` the data first.

```
const max = Math.max.apply(null, data.map((point) => point.y));
const min = Math.min.apply(null, data.map((point) => point.y));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.map` to get right min and max values.

```
var data = [{name:"s", y:2},{name:"e",y:90},{name:"tt",y:9},{name:"se",y:10}];


var values = data.map(function( obj ) {
    return obj.y;
}); 

var min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
```

If you are using `ES6`, then you can get rid of `.apply` and replace it with spread operator.

```
var min = Math.min(...values);
var max = Math.max(...values);
```

Comment: You can't pass an array to `Math.max`. You need to use `apply`.

Comment: @fubar Fixed it.